# Calculating Allowable Error using Calculus

Tags: calculus

What is the allowable error in measuring the edge of the cube that is intended to hold 8 cu m. ; if the error of the computed volume is not to exceed 0.03 cu. m?

The Answer is 0.0025

Ok. Im supposed to solve this using calculus. I know for a fact that V = E^3; I am not sure what allowable error is in engineering terms? (if it is an engineering term that is). I am guessing the "error of the computed volume" is some sort of rate? I just don't see how I can put the pieces together/relate the equations to form something I can apply differentiation on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this kind of thing is often taught in first-year calculus and uses differentials. This is a quick way to solve such problems, and does not guarantee that the answer is completely correct, though it does give excellent approximations if the errors are relatively small. It also gives the student practice in using differentials as opposed to derivatives. The basic idea is that your "allowable errors" are differentials which are similar to related rates (which you probably have already done).

Your base formula is

$$V=E^3$$

Substituting your given value $V=8$ and solving for $E$,

$$E=\sqrt[3] V=\sqrt[3] 8=2$$

Differentiating the first equation and using differential notation,

$$dV=3E^2\,dE$$

Solving for $dE$,

$$dE=\frac{dV}{3E^2}$$

Substituting the values $E=2$, $dV=0.03$,

$$dE=\frac{.03}{3\cdot 2^2}=0.0025$$

If you want to wrap this up into one formula, you could use

$$dE=\frac{dV}{3V^{2/3}}$$